# Configure SiteMinder as AWS Cognito userpool identityProvider using SAML2

Tags: metadata, saml-2.0, siteminder, aws-userpools

When cognito sends the SAMLREQUEST to the IDP the request does not have all the information that the IDP is expecting.

SP is sending the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="assertionURL" Destination="destinaUrl" ID="_a4b38e68-8e69-4a5d-927b-01e16da92ca7" IssueInstant="2019-10-23T15:14:36.339Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:blah:blah</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

However through manual testing the following SAMLREQUEST works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://uat-marley.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse" Destination="https://ssofed-qa.metlife.com/affwebservices/public/saml2sso?SPID=urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-1_k4dn6EP6k" ID="_a4b38e68-8e69-4a5d-927b-01e16da92ca7" IssueInstant="2019-10-23T15:14:36.339Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:amazon:cognito:sp:us-east-1_k4dn6EP6k</saml2:Issuer>
<saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"/>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

The only difference is this line:

```
<saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"/>
```

Because AWS userpools identity federation config only needs IDP metadata in order to integrate with IDPS, I'm assuming I need to tweak the metadata in order to change the SAMLREQUEST to include the NamePolicyId element.

I have been using this doc to try different elements:
http://www.datypic.com/sc/saml2/s-saml-schema-metadata-2.0.xsd.html

I've also been using this website to build metadata: https://www.samltool.com/idp_metadata.php

Also:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-integrating-3rd-party-saml-providers.html

Idps sample metadata:

```
<EntityDescriptor ID="SM172d8336f5cde29cebbfed3478bc49c5ee3f72a813a3" entityID="urn:entity:id" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" ID="SM1d149b29837b56846f0e9a85ae92be6449ffd58ef1e" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <KeyInfo Id="myid" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <X509Data>
                    <X509IssuerSerial>
                        <X509IssuerName>
              issuer info
                        </X509IssuerName>
                        <X509SerialNumber>
                            number
                        </X509SerialNumber>
                    </X509IssuerSerial>
                    <X509Certificate>
          some cert
                    </X509Certificate>
                    <X509SubjectName>
          relevant info
                    </X509SubjectName>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="redirect url" />
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="post url" />
    </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

I want to know how I can tweak the idps metadata such that cognito knows to send this `<saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"/>`
in the SAMLREQUEST.

Thank you for any help in advance, I've been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: turns out the version of siteminder that I was trying to integrate with had a bug where they could not accept base 64 encoded string with new line characters even though base64 encoding can have new line chars. The stuff above was a non issue